# Error al enviar una notificación push desde php a app Android

Tags: php, android, android-studio, firebase, push-notification

Hola comunidad de Stackoverflow, he estado mirando varias secciones de la misma pregunta pero no he encontrado una buena respuesta, entonces decidí formular la mía con mi respecto problema, mi problema es la siguiente, he creado una app que recibe notificaciones mediante un apartado web escrito en el lenguaje PHP, la app está conectada a Firebase y hecha en Android Studio, a continuación les proporciono el apartado PHP:

```
    <?php
$titulo = $_GET['titulo'];
$mensaje = $_GET['mensaje'];

 ////////ENVÍO DE NOTIFICACIÓN/////////
$fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$token = 'acá está el token';
$apiKey = 'acá está el api cloud key';
$notification = ['title' => $titulo, 'body' => $mensaje, 'icon' => 'myIcon', 'sound' => 'mySound'];
$extraNotificationData = ["message" => $notification, "moredata" => 'dd'];
$fcmNotification = [
        
'to' => $token,
'notification' => $notification, 'data' => $extraNotificationData];
$headers = ['Authorization: key=' . $apiKey, 'Content-Type: application/json'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fcmUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Enviar Notificación</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="generar_notificacion" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="titulo">
    <input type="text" name="mensaje">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Es un apartado muy simple ya que es de prueba, mi intención inicial es hacer la prueba a un dispositivo en concreto y luego a todos los dispositivos que luego tendré que averiguar por que no tengo idea de como hacerlo, siguiendo con la pregunta, cuando abro la web, sin siquiera hacer el envío me sale el siguiente error:

```
ERROR: {"multicast_id":17618352122632735,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

También cuando lo envío aparece el mismo error y no sé a que se debe, la app está formulada correctamente, me tomé la molestia de revisar antes de publicar la pregunta, agradecería mucho si pudieran ayudarme a encontrar la solución, gracias de ante mano

Comment: Haz las tres verificaciones [indicadas aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36467305/5587982), pues puede que tengas alguna credencial errónea. Aunque me extraña que quieras pasar por PHP para esto, ¿por qué no lo haces usando código de Firebase directamente? Cuando toque ponerlo en producción, tendrás que programar un sincronizador para conectar a PHP, corriendo el riesgo de que no quede bien programado y añadiendo trabajo suplementario al proceso de desarrollo.

Comment: Seguí un tutorial de como hacerlo con PHP por eso esto, aunque quisiera hacerlo en Python, siento que sería un mejor manejo, pero no tengo el conocimiento para trabajar con notificaciones push con firebase desde Python...

Comment: Pero Firebase tiene código nativo (Java) para implementar desde Android directamente usando el SDK de Firebase ([ver aquí](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=es-419)), no entiendo por qué quieres pasar por otros lenguajes, ¿no es una App para Android?

Comment: Si, es para Android, pero la idea es tener un apartado en la computadora para hacer notificaciones personalizadas y que no solo yo pueda usarlo desde la consola de Firebase, no se si llego a explicarme correctamente

Comment: Para ejemplificar, la app recibe notificaciones por parte de una persona, las notificaciones como el titulo y el mensaje lo podes escribir en un apartado gráfico y cuando haces la petición de envío, cuya notificación creada será mandado a todos los dispositivos que tengan la app instalada

Comment: Ah ya, o sea, quieres dar la posibilidad de enviar notificaciones desde el PC también, no desde la aplicación.

Comment: Si, exactamente.

Comment: ¿Verificaste que la API Key, la dirección del proyecto y demás credenciales son correctas?

Answer (score 0):

El código que pusiste funciona a la perfección. ¿Pusiste el server key del cloud?

Porque mucha gente se confunde y pone el **apikey** que no es el mismo, para enviar notificaciones a un usuario o usuarios en particular/es tienes que anteriormente capturar el token, esto podes hacerlo con esta función:

```
this.afMessaging.getToken
    .subscribe(
      (token) => {
        if(token){
          // token present
          this.notifications = true;
        }
      },
      (error) => { console.error(error); },
    )
```

Yo las guardo en el servidor y después consultas por medio del mail, etc y obtienes el token que guardaste.

Saludos.